# Change the range of pivot table with EPPlus of an existing file

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, epplus

Is it possible to change the range of pivot table and then refresh the values with EPPlus of an existening file?

Now I use EPPlus in conjunction with Excel Interopt... EPPlus add new sheet with data in an existing xlsx with a well defined pivot table... then I refresh the data source with code like this:

```
private bool RefreshPivotTable(string file, string sheetName, string pivotTableName, string sourceData)
    {
        try
        {
            Type excelType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");

            dynamic excel = Activator.CreateInstance(excelType);
            dynamic workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(file);
            dynamic sheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];
            dynamic pivotTable = sheet.PivotTables(pivotTableName);

            pivotTable.SourceData = sourceData;
            pivotTable.RefreshTable();

            workbook.Save();
            workbook.Close();
            excel.Application.Quit();

            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But I Would like do all with EPPlus. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With EPPlus:

```
            var excelWorkbook = new FileInfo(excelWorkbookPath);
            using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(excelWorkbook))
            {
                var rawDataWorksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[RawDataWorksheetName];

                var pivotTableWorksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[PivotTableWorksheetName];
                pivotTableWorksheet.PivotTables[0 /* Or whichever index */].CacheDefinition.SourceRange = rawDataWorksheet.Cells[rawDataWorksheet.Dimension.Start.Row, rawDataWorksheet.Dimension.Start.Column, rawDataWorksheet.Dimension.End.Row, rawDataWorksheet.Dimension.End.Column];
            }
```

---

And if you're using a template Excel workbook (as opposed to creating a brand new workbook), you should also do the following:

1. Go to Pivot Table options and check 'Refresh data when opening the file': https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1859-excel-refresh-pivot-table-on-open.html.

[image: Refresh data when opening the file]

2. (Optional) If desired, **users** can disable 'Protected View' inside of their Excel installation: [http://www.corporatefocus.com/support/how-to-disable-protected-view-in-microsoft-excel#:~:text=In%20Excel%20go%20to%20File,Enable%20All%20Macros%20by%20default](http://www.corporatefocus.com/support/how-to-disable-protected-view-in-microsoft-excel#:%7E:text=In%20Excel%20go%20to%20File,Enable%20All%20Macros%20by%20default).

[image: Disable 'Protected View']

Answer (score -1):

I am afraid that is possible only in part.

Looking at the [EPPlus documentation](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Projects/EPPlus), you will find documentation about Pivot Tables and its [Pivot Cache](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/EPPlus/EPPlus/ExcelPivotCacheDefinition) with [Source Range](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/EPPlus/EPPlus/ExcelPivotCacheDefinition/P/SourceRange) and similar properties. But no account is given about refreshing pivot tables. This should be done upon opening the workbook in Excel - maybe that is soon enough for you?

Anyway, my understanding of EPPlus is reading manipulating the structure of Excel *files*, not doing any calculations in them - that remains in the domain of the Excel application itself.

**Amendment:** I have to correct myself: general calculation is possible as of EPPlus Version 4 according to [this tutorial page](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Formula-Calculation), you can run `worksheet.Calculate()` and other commands. But still no mentioning of pivot tables.